# Yii Query Builder multiple where clauses

Tags: yii, query-builder

I noticed in my stack that my query wasn't being executed correctly as I had multiple where clauses in my querybuilder. So I looked at this post [Multiple call where in Yii Query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562823/multiple-call-where-in-yii-query-builder)

Applied what i'd read, but still the query doesn't combine the where statements. What am I doing wrong?

```
            $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ....
        ->where(array('in', 'u.id', $licenses), array('and', 'i.date_added > DATE_SUB(u.date_expired, INTERVAL  30 DAY)'));
        //->where(array('and', 'i.date_added > DATE_SUB(u.date_expired, INTERVAL  30 DAY)'));
        //->where(array('and', 'u.date_expired > CURDATE()'))
        ->group('u.id');
```

These were 3 individual statements, but I combined them as I read, but still the same result. Only 1 where clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `andWhere` method. This method is putting the `AND` keyword so you juste need the condition:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ....
    ->where(array('in', 'u.id', $licenses));
    ->andWhere('i.date_added > DATE_SUB(u.date_expired, INTERVAL  30 DAY)');
    ->andWhere('u.date_expired > CURDATE()')
    ->group('u.id');
```

Comment: Thanks, just to note that it's in the docs as `addwhere()` but the actual method is `andWhere()`