# Need help regarding mysql query to search all columns as requested with different possible combinations

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am currently working on a php project where i stuck at mysql query to search all possible variations of requests in search results.

Here is my database columns example:

```
column 1: title
column 2: description
column 3: category
column 4: subcategory
column 5: city
column 6: state
column 7: type
```

and i want results like:
search keyword  match in title or description + state + category + type

or

search keyword  match in title or description + state + subcategory + type

or

search keyword  match in title or description + city + category + type

or

search keyword  match in title or description + city + subcategory + type

or

search keyword  match in title or description + type

or

search keyword  match in title or description + state

or

search keyword  match in title or description + city

or

search keyword  match in title or description

or

state

or

city

or

type

or

category

or anything possible we get from search query.

search contains options like:

keyword search ( optional ) + state selection ( optional ) +city selection ( optional ) + category selection ( optional ) + subcategory selection ( optional ) + type selection ( optional )

so we can search for anything keyword or state only without keyword or whatever we need.

Comment: Based on my experience this task is easier to solve on the app side (i.e. in php). When using query builders it becomes pretty simple.

Comment: any example for this

Comment: In Yii it will be [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668553/yii-query-builder-multiple-where-clauses) except use can use `orWhere` instead of `andWhere` and stack them depending on what user have selected. Other PHP frameworks have similar functions.

Comment: ok i got it but i need further help, tell me how can i write for this query  `search keyword match in title or description + state + subcategory + type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a query in PHP by adding AND conditions depending on what user have selected. Example with PDO (no framework needed):

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

// get this data from user inputs
$search_keyword = 'bla';
$conditions = [ 
    "category" => 'cat',
    "subcategory" => 'sale',
    "city" => 'auburn',
    "state" => 'NY',
    "type" => 'offer',
];


$sql = "SELECT * from data_table WHERE (title = :search OR description = :search)";

$binds = ['search' => $search_keyword];
foreach($conditions as $col => $val){
    $conditions[] = $col . ' = :' . $col;
    $binds[$col] = $val;
}

if ($conditions) {
    $sql .= " AND " . implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($binds);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: In the example above you just searched for keyword in title & description and type, but i want to say that type is separately provided, as per my query: `search keyword match in title or description + state + subcategory + type`  query will contains:  `keyword = bla & type = offer & subcategory = sale & city = auburn`,    so here we have to match keyword with title & description only and all others queries are separately provided to match.